# Passing list into query in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to execute an SQL Query in python. I have a pandas dataframe which is necessary for passing *CompanyId* column to my query.

```
data["CompanyId"].head()

0    16559
1    16753
2    16757
3    17491
4    17532
```

I want to use the *CompanyId* inside the `IN` operator of SQL. I tried,

```
x = ",".join(str(data["CompanyId"]))

myquery =  "SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE CompanyId IN (" +  x  + ")"
```

But no chance. I can create the very same query thanks to the paste function in `R` like,

```
paste0('SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE CompanyId IN (',paste(data[,"CompanyId"],collapse=","),')')
```

But I am unable to the this in `python`.

At the end, I'd like to execute the query like below,

```
pd.read_sql_query(myquery,conn)
```

Btw, I am not sure if this is the best way to execute a query through python. I am open to any advise that makes my life easier.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'no chance'? Are you getting errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: I meant, It gives inappropriate string output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're converting your dataframe into a string, rather than mapping its elements to strings. This would change

`",".join(str(data["CompanyId"]))`

to

`",".join(map(str,df["CompanyId"]))`

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'companyId':12},{'companyId':19},{'companyId':121}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
ids = [str(x) for x in df['companyId'].tolist()]
myquery =  f"SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE CompanyId IN ({','.join(ids)})"
print(myquery)
```

output

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE CompanyId IN (12,19,121)
```

Comment: This also gives the right output. I cannot upvote because of my reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the ids to strings using astype.

```py
ids = ','.join(data['CompanyId'].astype(str).to_list())

myquery =  f"SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE CompanyId IN ({ids})"
```